# Is explicit specialization of a class member template function possible with C++20 or newer?

Tags: c++, c++20

I have a enum and a description struct with a fully specialized template method to convert the enum values to a string. The code works with msvc, but I get a warning with clang and an error with gcc. How or where can I find out, if the code is valid to the latest C++ standard?

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>

enum class E : uint8_t
{
  E1,
  E2
};

struct E_Description
{
    template <E>
    static constexpr auto to_string () noexcept;

    template <>
    static constexpr auto to_string<E::E1> () noexcept
    {
        return "E::E1";
    }
    
    template <>
    static constexpr auto to_string<E::E2> () noexcept
    {
        return "E::E2";
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto str{ E_Description::to_string<E::E1>() };
}
```

This code works as expected with msvc. With clang I get the warning "warning: explicit specialization cannot have a storage class" and gcc does not compile with the error "error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope". Is the code is not valid to the standard? And if so - why?

Answer (score 5):

Clang is correct that the storage class specifier `static` is not allowed on the explicit specialization, see [[temp.expl.spec]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.expl.spec#2).  It should be removed. MSVC is wrong to not provide a diagnostic due to the violation.

GCC is wrong in not accepting the specializations inside the class scope since resolution of [CWG 727](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#727). They have not implemented this defect report yet and have [open bug reports](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85282) for it. GCC in its current state wants you to declare the explicit specializations outside the class scope.